# How to stop DHCP when I assign a static IP address in Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, dhcp

I’m running an Ubuntu 17.10 server for my game servers since its the only platform where Steam is supported by Valve. It’s a new Ubuntu  17.10 install without any major changes in the install.

I have set a static IP address in `/etc/network/interfaces` but my card keeps recieving a DHCP address as well. So basically the server has my static ip `192.168.1.13` and a DHCP address `192.168.1.226`.

But how can I stop the dhcpclient from acquiring a DHCP assigned IP address?

My network interface shows:

```
auto ens18
iface ens18 inet static
    address 192.168.1.13
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 5):

Networking changed in Ubuntu 17.10 so adding anything to `/etc/network/interfaces` won't change anything.
It now uses [Netplan](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan).

To disable DHCP and set a static IP:

First, find out what your network interface is called, run `ls /sys/class/net`

The output will probably be something like `enp6s0  lo`.

`lo` is the loopback interface so `enp6s0` will be your network interface (in this example).

Create a new config file inside of /etc/netplan

e.g `sudo nano /etc/netplan/02-netcfg.yaml`

Enter the following to configure a static IP of `192.168.1.13` where `enp6s0` is the name of your network interface.

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp6s0:
            addresses: [192.168.1.13/24]
            dhcp4: no
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
```

Then run the following two commands:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: Probably, you need add `nameservers: addresses: [192.168.1.1]` at the end of file

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Ubuntu 20.04 on a RaspberryPI, `cloud-init` is the culprit as can be witnessed from the file `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

Simply delete the file or comment out the offending lines